# EmberJS History/Undo

Tags: javascript, ember.js, undo

**Edit: I've made my own implementation which is on [GitHub](https://github.com/ignasbernotas/ember-history)**

I was wondering, is there a built-in feature in ember that allows to save states of objects/arrays? In our app we've built our own undo/history implementation for a particular Ember.ArrayController, but it seems to be buggy and slow (in Firefox). So I'm wondering if there's anything out there that would replace our script.

Basically what we use it for:
Users add, edit, modify elements in that array and sometimes they'd like to undo/redo their changes. At the moment we limit the amount of states to 30 (may not be the optimal amount).

Any thoughts/links are appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've implemented a mixin "Memento" which tracks changes of the properties defined in `mementoProperties` array. It supports *normal* properties as well as *array* properties.

The basic idea is the following: when the mixin is initialized, it registers itself as observer for property changes. A property change adds a new item to the `memento` array which represents the history of changes made. Invoking `undo` sets the property to the state before the change has been made. `redo` respectively resets the value.

The [mixin](https://github.com/pangratz/ember-memento/blob/master/app/lib/memento.js) is hosted on GitHub at **[ember-memento](https://github.com/pangratz/ember-memento)**. It can be used as follows, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/9fa95/:

```js
App.obj = Ember.Object.create(Ember.Memento, {
    name: 'hello',
    myArray: [],
    age: 12,

    mementoProperties: 'name age myArray'.w()
});

App.obj.get('myArray').pushObject(1);
App.obj.get('myArray').pushObject(2);
App.obj.get('myArray').pushObject(3);
App.obj.set('name', 'hubert');
App.obj.get('myArray').pushObject(4);
App.obj.set('age', 190);
App.obj.get('myArray').pushObjects(['a', 'b']);

App.obj.undo(); // myArray = [1,2,3,4]
App.obj.undo(); // age = 12
App.obj.undo(); // myArray = [1,2,3]
App.obj.undo(); // name = 'hello'
App.obj.redo(); // name = 'hubert'
App.obj.redo(); // myArray = [1,2,3,4]
App.obj.redo(); // age = 190
```

Comment: The solution itself is awesome, however because ember doesn't have something like updateProperties instead of setProperties, I cannot make multiple changes to the object and not trigger the observers multiple times. Though you solution works as expected! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've updated the mixin and added an `updateProperties` method which only adds 1 history item for multiple value changes. If you have any further suggestions, please open an issue in the repo. Cheers!

Comment: I've created a similar implementation just way more simple than yours. My implementation is for global history not just for an object. Check it out https://github.com/ignasbernotas/ember-history/ :)

Comment: @Ignas Nice! Don't forget to add it to https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/wiki/Modules